# hashlib.sha256 returned some weird characters in python

Tags: python, encryption, sha, hmac

In javascript the code below returned

**eec097af19ad461ac825ccce57a012543da33c986e4607475e1fe5c6dc098d0a**

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.1/build/rollups/hmac-sha512.js"></script>
<script>
   var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "Secret");
</script>
```

In python same logic returned some weird characters like �����F�%��W�T=�<�nFG^���   �

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
hash = hmac.new('Secret', "Message", hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

I think they should return same hash as i have used same algorithm for both. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try hexdigest()

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
hash = hmac.new('Secret', "Message", hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```